# What's the most efficient way to merge chained git branches that are based on each other into master?

Tags: git

I often find myself working with multiple branches, each one based on its predecessor. This allows me to break down huge work items into multiple functional changes, without waiting for each PR I create to be reviewed before I check in.

Example, say I have feature foo. I will usually have a set of branches like so:

```
/me/foo/part1
/me/foo/part2 (based on /me/foo/part1)
/me/foo/part3 (based on /me/foo/part2)
/me/foo/part4 (based on /me/foo/part3)
```

As I update Part1 (due to code reviews or merges from Master), I will "propagate" the changes each time from part 1 into part 2 by merging. This is generally a painless quick process.

My question is about the stage of "repointing" parts as I start merging branches into master.

In the example above, once Part1 is ready, it will be merged into master (painless).

However, I then need to base Part2 on master (so it can too be merged). To do this (once Part1 is merged), I will issue a merge request from master to Part2.

I want this merge to be as painless as merging Part1 into Part2 was (or even easier, as usually there are very few changes when I merge Part1 into Master, so the trees should be identical)

However, this stage specifically always comes with a ton of conflicts.

Am I missing a step that would make the "re-pointing" of Part2 into Master be easier?

Comment: I do not see why you _need_ to merge master into your feature branch after the branch that was used as its base is merged into master. If fearure1 branch was not rewritten (therefore, its original revisions are already part of master), you shoild be able to create a PR of feature2 into master without issues. _If_ you had moved feature1 around then we could be talking about other steps to make sure to not bring feature1's original revisions into the equation, but that is not the case so.... Can you elaborate on why you merge master into feature2?

Comment: @eftshift0: Thanks for the reply. I am not that well versed with git, so bear with me. My situation is this.

Branch1 is based off main. Published a PR with a target branch of Main
Branch2 is based off Branch1. Published a PR with a target branch of Branch1
etc.

The reason the PR is published with a different target branch is so that code reviwers arent lost in the code (since if I base it on main in the PR, it will contain changes from branch1 as well)

After I merge Branch1, I need to change the PR to be based on main (maybe that's my mistake?). That immediatly complains on conflict

Comment: Ok... that's interesting.... and if you are a newbie, you are doing pretty well, quite frankly so.... kudos! Now.... if you are doing it like that, there are no reason for there to be conflicts _unless_ in master there were changes introduced that touched on code that you are modifying in feature2... which is par for the course. Is there a reason for there _not_ to be a conflict? Take one of those conflict blocks (where you think a conflict makes no sense) and show us how code looks like in these three revisions (update the question with them): `feature2`, `master` and `feature1`.

Comment: Actually, do not use `feature1` in my request. Use the revision that comes out of this: `git merge-base master feature2` (which should be `feature1` but just in case).

Comment: Not really a newbie... Just have not had a lot of experience with git other than the 4 or 5 usual commands (most of my adult life source contol was SourceSafe/SourceDepot or SVN).  That's exactly the point - there should not be conflicts in most places. And yet, when it sees two parts of the code that are the same, it treats it as if they come from two separate places. I am close to merging Part 5 into master, and will need to do this two-step - will update the question with what I mean and ping you in the comments. Thanks!

Comment: hmm.... a basic question: You are **not** squashing when merging, right?

Comment: Hmmm... Good point. I am not, but we are using ADO and I am pretty sure it squashes when you merge a PR.

Comment: In AzDO there are 4 merge strategies you can use when you complete a PR. Merge is the *only* one that might not rewrite the commits from the source branch. (Squash, rebase and ff, and semi-linear merge aka rebase merge, can all rewrite commits.) You said you're "pretty sure" you're using squash. You should be able to pull up any PR and see which was one used for that PR.

Comment: Yeah, verified. We always squash.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok.... that is starting to make sense then. If there is a squash when merging `feature1`, git is *not* really able to see that `feature2`'s changes are only those changes that start from what you merged in `feature1` already because the squash commit for `feature1` is a completely separate commit from `feature1` as you have it in the history of `feature2` and so, when merging, it *won't* use `feature1` (the original branch) as the last common ancestor between `master`
and `feature2` but rather the *starting point* of `feature1` (the original branch), hence, it will consider **all** changes that make up `feature1` **and** `feature2` as what you are trying to merge from `feature2` into `master`... but you have already introduced changes from `feature1` into `master`. **Bottom line**: do not expect this to be a smooth merge. :-D

If that is the case, it is still manageable, you just need to work a little more to be able to get `feature2` in shape after you have merged its base branch:

```
git rebase --onto master feature1 feature2
```

`feature1` there is the *original* `feature1` as it is in the history of `feature2` . This way you are rebasing all revisions of `feature2` onto `master` making sure to *not* bring over the original revisions of `feature1` (which have been squashed... so git is *not* really able to see them as merged).

Squashing can make life a little miserable so you need to be careful. It's not like it can't be solved (as I have just showed)... you just need to understand what is going on to figure out what to do in each step.

Comment: Thanks!! I will try rebasing and see how works. Feature1/Feature2 are the branch names here, right?

Comment: `me/foo/part1`, `me/foo/part2`, I guess.

Comment: If `me/foo/part1` has moved and is not part of `me/foo/part2` (in your repo), then use the ID of the last commit of the old `me/foo/part1` that is in `me/foo/part2`: `git rebase --onto master the-commit-id-from-old-me/foo/part1 me/foo/part2`

Comment: ... or count the commits that make up `me/foo/part2` past `me/foo/part1`... suppose it's 4 revisions: `git rebase --onto master me/foo/part2~4 me/foo/part2`. They all do the same thing.

Comment: Okay, using this method is SO MUCH LESS PAINFUL than what I have been doing.

Thanks etshift.

Comment: I partied too soon. 

After I finished the multiple rebase steps and tried pushing, Git decided that the remote branch was ahead of me (this may be due to something I did in AzDO - I'll have to wait for the next part to be sure). When I pulled, it went into the Awful Merge I got when I tested merging with master.

Comment: I'll try to be more careful next time around and see how much and if it helps.\

Comment: I think you are better prepared for the task right now.

Comment: Final tally: I think I'll go back to the old sucky way w/o rebase. Rebase adds a ton of steps. some of them quite confusing, especially when it reaches a merge that ends up having no content. + now that I tried it twice, the rebase --onto runs into even more issues than merge in some cases (it does do it in smaller steps, so it's easier in that respect), but defintely not worth the extra time :( Thanks for all the help though! @eftshift0